# MetaMask - lost connection when page is loaded on browser launch

Tags: metamask

When launching a Chrome/Firefox Tab `ethereum.send` is never resolved.

The following warnings occur:

```
contentscript.js:1 MetamaskContentscript - lost connection to MetaMask Background Multiplex
s @ contentscript.js:1
contentscript.js:1 MetamaskContentscript - lost connection to MetaMask muxed traffic for channel "provider" failed.
s @ contentscript.js:1
contentscript.js:1 MetamaskContentscript - lost connection to MetaMask muxed traffic for channel "publicConfig" failed.
```

This question refers to [This Issue on Github](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/7221)

Comment: Did you find a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found one workaround which does not really solve the problem but simply reloads the page on its first load. I am still open for better solutions.

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

The solution refers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985507/one-time-page-refresh-after-first-page-load) stackoverflow post.